# WooCommerce Variation/Attribute pictures for all tiers

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a product in WooCoomerce where I want to present to the vistor different product pictures when they are choosing a new variable.

So I have added this in Attributes

```
Name  Values
Size: 5 mm  double wrap | 5 mm bracelet
Material: Natural brown | dark brown w/ green sides
Fonts: Times New roman | Uppercase
```

In Variation I have *Any Size - Natural Brow - Any Font* and I've set a picture for that variation.  In the post that works great.

The problem is that I would like to let the user see what kind of font type they can choose.

So I did *Any Size - Any Material - Times New Roman* and attached a picture to that.

Here's a screendump of the settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyJkq.png all is enabled.

But the picture of Times New Roman never shows up if I only choose the last dropdown in the product page.

Am I completly wrong that this possible or am I doing something wrong?